# Intellisense without project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

Has anyone got Intellisense to work on Visual Studio Code in a single file (so no project). I wasn't able to find much info with the most significant one being from Feb 2016 stating that Intellisense on single files [would be worked on](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/47).
I hope someone is informed enough to help me as i can't wrap my head around having to build a project to use Intellisense.

Thanks to all!

Edit: added link

Comment: Without a project, how do you expect it to know what references you have?

Comment: Just very basic keyword like 'class' or 'if' are completed. 'string' or 'float' are not recognized which shouldn't need references. Maybe this is just how things work in C#?

Comment: @MarekLegris ok, but those basic things come from somewhere right?  A specific _version_ of C#?  `string` is defined in the `System` namespace, how does a single .cs file know about all these things?  It needs some sort of metadata.  You can certainly have syntax highlighting without all this, but you will need a project for intellisense

Comment: @maccettura Excuse me but I'm still new to the C# 'ecosystem'. In C++, for example, vs code gets all these references without a project.

Comment: C++ doesn't have target frameworks. It results in native binaries.

Comment: What made me ask this question though is the response from the collaborator of vs code's support for c# (see updated question)